# I have the jetty version appearing on my 404 error page

Tags: java, http, jetty

I have a problem with a 404 error page in which I use jetty, I wanted to know how I can make the version that jetty is in disappear from there? example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmLEy.png)

I don't want the jetty version to appear, and I really don't know where I can look to remove this because the code isn't mine and I wasn't the one who installed jetty

I looked a lot but I really don't know where it can be or where to move it so that the jetty version comes out, and I really need to remove it because it's a customer request

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom error pages in your web.xml (`webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`) by adding an `error-page` block:

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/my_custom_404.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Source: https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#custom-error-pages